# Finding length of a vector that is normal to a plane to the origin

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus

I'm working on this question
Find the perpendicular distance from the origin to the plane $x+2y+2z=6$. I looked into the solution and it says the plane has a normal vector $(1,2,2)$ due to the coefficient of the plane equation. Then it picked an arbitrary point $P =(6,0,0)$ on the plane and use the projection equation of PO onto the vector $<1,2,2>$ to solve for distance.
I understand the logic for using the projection equation, but my confusion is that, how do we know the normal vector from the plane starts at the point $(6,0,0)$, if we want to project $PO$ on the vector, doesn't vector need to start at point $P$?

Comment: The community has got you covered. I'd suggest a better title still..

Comment: Vector is just a direction. Say perp from origin to plane is $OH$ then $|OH| = |OP| \cos\theta$ (think $\triangle OHP$). Now you don't know the length of $|OH|$ but you know the direction of $OH$, which is the normal vector $ \frac{1}{3} (1, 2, 2)$. Taking dot product with unit normal will give you $|OH|$.

Comment: Sorry, I must be missing something, Right, I understand how the geometry works of the triangle with points OHP. Where I don't get is that, how can we know the vector <1,2,2> starts at the point P(since P was chosen at arbitrary) and the idea of taking the normal vector <1,2,2>  to be OH seems out of nowhere. Maybe I need a more in-depth understanding of vector. it seems to me that a vector is just an arrow pointing into a direction from some point in the space, so Im confused on how can assume this normal vector <1,2,2> can start at any point on the plane.

Comment: Plane P: $1x+2y+2z-6=0$; Point O:$(0,0,0)$

Distance $d(O;P)=\dfrac{|1\text{x}0+2\text{x}0+2\text{x}0-6|}{\sqrt{1^2+2^2+2^2}}=\dfrac23$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that is simple; let's talk about the general case. Choose a point $P(x,y,z)$ on the plane $\Pi:ax+by+cz=1$, which has a normal vector $\vec{n_1}=(r,s,t)$. ($r,s,t$ can be easily calculated.)

Since $\vec{OP}\parallel\vec{n_1}$, we let $x=ru,y=su,z=tu$. And, because $P$ is on $\Pi$, we have $ax+by+cz=1$, or $aru+bsu+ctu=1$. So $u=\frac{1}{ar+bs+ct}$, $P(\frac{r}{ar+bs+ct},\frac{s}{ar+bs+ct},\frac{t}{ar+bs+ct})$. Length can be calculated easily then.

Answer (score 1):

This problem can be solved by the method of Lagrange multipliers.

Let $$L=x^2 +y^2+z^2 - \lambda (x+2y+2z-6)$$

Set $$0=\frac{\partial L}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial L}{\partial y}=\frac{\partial L}{\partial z}=\frac{\partial L}{\partial \lambda}$$

This yields $2x=y=z$.  This along with the equation for the plane gives the result.

That is, by minimizing $L$, the point $p=(x,y,z)$ on the plane closest to the origin is found.  Once you have $p$, just compute $|p|=\left( x^2+y^2+z^2\right)^{1/2}$.

Comment: Thanks for the solution but I was really asking about an idea that is out of my comprehension

Comment: https://www.personal.psu.edu/sxj937/Notes/Lagrange_Multipliers.pdf

Comment: https://mathworld.wolfram.com/LagrangeMultiplier.html